# jQuery will not work on page from snippet or file

Tags: jquery, forms, wp-enqueue-script

I've been banging my head against the wall on this, My jQuery code runs perfect in CodePen, the WP site in console also runs it perfect, however I simply can not get it to run on the actual WooCommerce My Account Billing Address page no matter what.

My jQuery:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // Your code in here
    jQuery('#billing_test').on('change', function () {
        myFunc();
    })
    function myFunc() {
        // your function code
        var complex_name = jQuery('#billing_test').val();

        var suburb = jQuery('#billing_suburb').val();

        if (complex_name == 'mr') {
            alert('works');
            jQuery("#billing_suburb").val('LDM');
            jQuery('#billing_postcode').val('5000');
        }
    }
})
```

I've tried adding via Code Snippets to no luck so tried a script file with the following code:

```
function my_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'test', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/test.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );
```

But still nothing. Any and all help will be really grateful as I've attempted everything I could but still nothing.

I have also tried replacing the `$` with `jQuery`, tried the `$.noConflict()` as well.

Added script manually and it is in the inspect as well.

HTML

```
<p class="form-row my-css" id="billing_test_field" data-priority=""><label for="billing_test" class="">Test</label><span
        class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><select name="billing_test" id="billing_test" class="select "
            data-allow_clear="true" data-placeholder="Title">
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            <option value="mr">Mr</option>
            <option value="ms" selected='selected'>Ms</option>
        </select></span></p>
```

How do I not use if and else if to match the conditions:

```
if (complex_name == 'eldogleneast') {
   jQuery("#billing_suburb").val('ELD');
   jQuery('#billing_postcode').val('0157');
}
    else if (complex_name == 'eldoglen'){
                jQuery("#billing_suburb").val('ELD');
   jQuery('#billing_postcode').val('0157');
             }
```

Comment: Is the file loaded? (Check browser's network tab.) How are you testing?

Comment: File is coming through , can see it in inspect. Did testing through the console

Comment: I imagine the #billing_test is not part of the dom when the page loads, so try delegating the change event to the first parent that's not dynamic. Worst case, you can delegate it to the document. In other words `jQuery(document).on('change', '#billing_test'`...

Comment: @PetarPetrov Tried that still nothing ```                
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(document).on('change','#billing_test', function () {
        myFunc();
    }) ```

Comment: Can we see some HTML markup? Only the chunk with the billing_test. But copy it from the source of the page, not the inspector. Add it to the question.

Comment: @PetarPetrov Added it to the code

Comment: Weird... I added the same custom field with PHP and it works. Are you selecting the Mr option from the field?

Comment: did you check your browsers dev tools for the error message? WooCommerce is off topic here, and so are generic javascript questions. If you have a general jQuery question it should go on stackoverflow instead

Comment: @PetarPetrov Got the error, the file being loaded was in parent folder not child folder. However the code is only running once, so if I select the field it changes but then it does not change again once I pick another one

Comment: I'm using if and else if I'm guessing that's the problem , how do I ensure it runs still after a condition is met and it populates the field and then once I select again then it populates again another field

Comment: That's a JS question and should be directed to stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

The file was reading from parent theme directory not the child theme directory thus the issue of it not being read.

Found it from tracing the directory from the Network tab